# PHP generate two random numbers without repeating eachother neither previous numbers

Tags: php, random, repeat

I have the following code that should generate two random numbers and never repeat them if they have already been generated before. $ticket_number1 and $ticket_number2 are saved to database table 'tickets' in 'ticket1' and 'ticket2' fields respectively.
Something is wrong though, I tested the script with generated numbers being between 1 and 6, and I have had one result where both $ticket_number1 and $ticket_number2 were the same number (4 in this case) and that should not happen. After that I tested again and I got two different numbers (1 and 4) but they had already been given out before, so they should not had appeared again.
This means that this whole script isn't doing anything other than generating random numbers.
I was already told that `mysql_` has been deprecated but that is not the reason why the script doesn't work, right?
Any thoughts on how this should be to work properly?
Thanks for the help in advance.

```
function getTicket(){
    $count=1;
    while($count){
        $ticket_number = mt_rand(01990, 32000);
        $query = "SELECT ticket1 FROM `tickets`
        WHERE `ticket1` == '$ticket_number' or `ticket2` == '$ticket_number'";
        $count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
    }
    return $ticket_number;
}



$ticket_number1 = getTicket();
$ticket_number2 = getTicket();
```

Comment: why cant you just use an [auto incrementing key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)? Why do they have to be random numbers?

Comment: Are you saving these results to the database? Do you mean the numbers are same inone session or on subsequent calls

Comment: As you're not updating the database when you do get a valid random number, the SQL query is pretty meaningless

Comment: What Gordon said. Rule of thumb: "random" and "unique" in the same sentence is almost always an indication that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Gordon Being a raffle, makes more sense being random than sequential.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee Yes, they are being saved to database. The case were the two numbers were both the same is in the same running of the script. When it gave numbers that were already given before, it was in another running of the script.

Comment: @MarkBaker I have the code that updates the database, it comes right after this code, I just didn't paste it since it wasn't part of the problem.

Comment: okay. check my answer then. if its the same isntance, its because your set of values is less. For six numbers there is a 1 in 6 chance that the numbers will be same. For 4 numbers, there is a 1 in 4 chance that numbers will be same

Comment: @Alex I am not sure I understand. Is the point of that program to pick a random winning ticket? Can you update your question please and explain the scenario?

Comment: @Gordon The script should give the tickets. When a ticket is requested, it gives it by generating a random number. It has to be unique because there can't be two tickets with the same number.

Answer (score 0):

I am just shooting in the dark here, but if the numbers are in the same call i.e $ticket_number1 and $ticket_number2 are same in one call to the page, you can fix this by telling the function to reject an already chosen number

```
function getTicket($exclude=-1){
  $count=1;
  while($count){
    $ticket_number = mt_rand(01990, 32000);
    $query = "SELECT ticket1 FROM `tickets`
    WHERE `ticket1` == '$ticket_number' or `ticket2` == '$ticket_number'";
    $count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
    if(!$count)
       $count=$ticket_number==$exclude;

  }
  return $ticket_number;
}

$ticket_number1 = getTicket();
$ticket_number2 = getTicket($ticket_number1);
```

Comment: I tried your code about 7 times with the random number being between 1 and 6 and the two numbers given were always different, but it repeated numbers that were already given (for example, in the first try it gave the numbers 3 and 5 and in the forth try it gave numbers 3 and 6).
Therefore, it seems to work so that $ticket_number1 is not equal to $ticket_number2. But it doesn't restrict these two variables from being equal to numbers already given out.

Comment: to do that, you need to store the ticket numbers in the database when they are generated. php has no way of knowing wat ticket numbers came out in the last session unless you persist them in database or sessions. plus for such a small dataset, you'll run out of numbers pretty soon